# Using Regular expressions to format document

Tags: python, regex

I have a piece of text that goes like this -

```
Authority: soaplab.icapture.ubc.ca - EMBOSS seqret program. The sequence source is USA (Uniform Sequence Address). This means that you pass in a database name as the namespace.and an entry from the db as the id, e.g.db = embl and id = X13776. The input format is swiss.The output format is fasta.
```

Using regular expressions , I have to format text properly - put a space after full stop wherever the length of a sentence (between 2 full stops) is more than 7. An example in the given text is - e.g.db ... and swiss.The output format is ....

I used the following regular expression to match such full stops -

```
\.[^\.]{7,}\.
```

For example,

```
Input - The input format is swiss.The output format is fasta.
Output - The input format is swiss. The output format is fasta.

Input - from the db as the id, e.g.db = embl and id = X13776.
Output - from the db as the id, e.g. db = embl and id = X13776.
```

However, this matches entire sentence with a length of 7 and greater , instead of only the full stop. How do I only match those 2 cases I want ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj for example - 

Input - The input format is swiss.The output format is fasta.
Output - The input format is swiss. The output format is fasta.

Input - from the db as the id, e.g.db = embl and id = X13776.
Output - from the db as the id, e.g. db = embl and id = X13776.

Comment: please add the above comment to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use capturing group or a positive lookahead based regex inside `re.sub` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''The input format is swiss.The output format is fasta.
from the db as the id, e.g.db = embl and id = X13776.'''
>>> print(re.sub(r'\.([^.]{7,}\.)', r'. \1', s))
The input format is swiss. The output format is fasta.
from the db as the id, e.g. db = embl and id = X13776.
```

`[^.]{7,}` matches any character but not of a dot , 7 or more times. So there must be atleast 7 chars present in-between two dots.

---

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'\.(?=[^.]{7,}\.)', r'. ', s))
The input format is swiss. The output format is fasta. 
from the db as the id, e.g. db = embl and id = X13776.
```

`\.(?=[^.]{7,}\.)` matches the dot only if it is followed by a sentence which has atleast 7 chars. If yes, then replace the matched dot with dot + space.

---

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?<=\.)(?=[^.]{7,}\.)', r' ', s))
The input format is swiss. The output format is fasta. 
from the db as the id, e.g. db = embl and id = X13776.
```